# Place a link on a clickable object in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, styles

I have a Table row on my page which is clickable. Now I have to place a link on this row which, on clicked, does some different functionality.

Now when I click the link the onClick() function for Table row is called, but I want it to be called for link.

[image]

This is my row which, on clicked, opens the hotel page, and Show Map is a link which is supposed to open a map on the current page.

Now when I click on any part of row other than Show Map Link, the Hotel page should be opened while when I click show Hotel, the map should be shown.

Comment: please show what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some changes. Pass event argument to the onclick function

```
onclick = "myfunction(event)"
```

and then you have to place an id in the link (suppose: myLink)

```
function myfunction(e) {
    if($(e).attr('id') == "myLink") {
        return;
    }
    else 
        //do your row functionality
}
```

Comment: arguments for both functions are different. how should I handle this?

Comment: You have to do this in the onclick of tr tag